# How to combine rows with same ID but different values in certain columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, ejs, mysql2

| id | name | age | gender | hobby |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Max | 20 | Male | Skating |
| 1 | Max | 20 | Male | Running |
| 1 | Max | 20 | Male | Jogging |
| 2 | Tom | 24 | Male | Skating |
| 3 | Mary | 22 | Female | Dancing |

For example, I want to combine this table to look something like the table below or some equivalent of it, as I have an inner join and the result is as such above and I want to render it out with ejs, but I'm stuck since I have multiple rows with the same ID. Is there something that in mysql that could allow me to bring about the table below, or similar results? The best thing is being able to get the hobby column result back in an array for every id

| id | name | age | gender | hobby |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Max | 20 | Male | Skating, Running, Jogging |
| 2 | Tom | 24 | Male | Skating |
| 3 | Mary | 22 | Female | Dancing |

Comment: Yes. See the manual under aggregate functions - and note that you have no way at present of guarantting the order of hobbies, if that matters. But I would just handle this in your application code. Also, just to note that if this is a table (as opoosed to a query result), then it's not normalised.

Comment: It is a query result, my bad. The order of hobbies wouldnt matter I'm just gonna iterate over them to render it somewhere else.

Comment: Well, the 'somewhere else' is where I'd handle the presentation logic, but you have the option below, if you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using group_concat()

```
 select id, name, age, gender, group_concat(hobby) 
 from my_table 
 group by id, name, age, gender
```